# Can you make transactions using this method?

Tags: metamask

`let signature = await ethereum.request({ method: 'wallet_requestPermissions', params: [ { 'eth_accounts': { requiredMethods: ['signTypedData_v3'] } }] }); console.log(signature);`

Like, can I use this method to get the signature to make a signed transaction, without the metamask confirm message to pop-up? Please, can anyone help me?